# Javascript XML serialization (IE issue)

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xsd, xmlserializer

I use the following code to generate XML, see [codepen](http://codepen.io/heavenmaster/pen/pbyxRB)

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument ('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'root', null);

var somenamespace = "http://somenamespace.com/schema";
doc.documentElement.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/', 'xmlns:' + "pref", somenamespace);

var el1 = doc.createElementNS(doc.documentElement.namespaceURI, "el1");
doc.documentElement.appendChild(el1);

var el2 = doc.createElementNS(doc.documentElement.namespaceURI, "el2");
el1.appendChild(el2);

el2.setAttributeNS(somenamespace, "pref" + ":" + "foo", "bar");

var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var raw = serializer.serializeToString(doc);
document.body.innerText = raw;
```

It works as expected in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, but IE drops my `xmlns:prefix` where I set it and writes in other XML nodes.

Expected:

```
<root
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:pref="http://somenamespace.com/schema">
    <el1>
        <el2 pref:foo="bar"></el2>
    </el1>
</root>
```

IE:

```
<root
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <el1>
  <el2
   xmlns:pref="http://somenamespace.com/schema" pref:foo="bar">
  </el2>
 </el1>
</root>
```

What can I do to workaround and make IE write `xmlns` in the root element (where I set it)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I do to workaround and make IE write `xmlns` in the root
>   element (where I set it)?

### Nothing.

Your expected and actual XML are fully equivalent.  No compliant XML processor will treat the two forms differently.  You should not care either.

Comment: Sure, you are right that both are valid. What I care about is I explicitly set `doc.documentElement.setAttributeNS` on the root and want that it is serialized there. I hope that I miss something like `preserveXmlns` what I dont know

Comment: No, you missed the point of this answer.  Both are beyond *valid* (colloquially speaking -- *valid* actually means something very specific in XML); both are ***equivalent***.  Again, no compliant XML processor will care which form is used, and neither should you.